# How to load external files in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, toolbox

I have lots of models in QGIS 3.8. I´m translating them to Python scripts to still use in the Tollbox but qith reduced processing time.

Using the QGIS automatic "export model as Python script", I´m having some trouble to get any shapefile that are not load in QGIS.

I made a simple model that merge two external shapefiles, that´s the export result:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class JustMerge(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('MergedOutput', 'Merged Output', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Merge Layers
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': None,
            'LAYERS': [['C:/Shapes/File1.shp'],['C:/Shapes/File2.shp']],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['MergedOutput']
        }
        outputs['MergeLayers'] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['MergedOutput'] = outputs['MergeLayers']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Just Merge'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Just Merge'

    def group(self):
        return 'Just Merge'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Just Merge'

    def createInstance(self):
        return JustMerge()
```

> I got this error only when running the Script, the original model works perfectly:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Just Merge' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'MergedOutput' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 26, in processAlgorithm
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 114, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish=post_process, feedback=feedback, context=context)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 136, in runAlgorithm
feedback.reportError(msg)
TypeError: reportError(self, error: str, fatalError: bool): not enough arguments

Execution failed after 0.04 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Just Merge' finished
```

> I´m looking for the right way to call the external files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is that you're passing a list of list-of-strings as your layers parameter, not a list-of-strings.

I.e. instead of

```
   'LAYERS': [['C:/Shapes/File1.shp'],['C:/Shapes/File2.shp']],
```

You should be passing

```
   'LAYERS': ['C:/Shapes/File1.shp','C:/Shapes/File2.shp'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it likes how you defined your input layers. You should consider using the [new format for writing scripts](https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/02/easy-processing-scripts-comeback-in-qgis-3-6/) as it gets rid off a lot of waffle. For example, the following script let's you select multiple shapefiles (either loaded in QGIS or external) and runs the merge tool. As it is a native tool, it would output the name of the tool used (at least that is the behavour I have noticed):

```py
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsFeatureSink, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsProject, QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
import processing

@alg(name="ex_new", label=alg.tr("Just Merge"), group="Just Merge", group_label=alg.tr("Just Merge"))
@alg.input(type=alg.MULTILAYER, name="INPUT", label="Input layer")
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name="OUTPUT", label="Merged Output")
def testalg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Description goes here. (Don't delete this! Removing this comment will cause errors.)
    """        
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, feedback)

    # Merge Layers
    alg_params = {
        'LAYERS': parameters['INPUT'],
        'CRS': None,
        'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
    }
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}
    processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, is_child_algorithm=True, context=context, feedback=feedback)   

    return {}
```

Comment: Almost that. What I am looking for is to insert a file that is not declared as input, the user does not have the option to change this file, every time they execute, the same file will be selected. So I believe the @ alg.input method doesn't satisfy. I am reading your indication looking for answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

It´s need to define the files and call them by their names, not by their path.

```py
        def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):

        File1 = 'C:/Shapes/File1.shp'
        File2 = 'C:/Shapes/File2.shp'

        # Merge Layers
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': None,
            'LAYERS': [File1,File2],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['MergedOutput']
        }
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)